# Why does "ssh-agent && ssh-add" only work once?

Tags: ssh-agent

Have a look at the following shell session:

```
niklas@llw ~ % ssh-agent && ssh-add
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ZzWYJAmK8809/agent.8809; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=8810; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 8810;
Enter passphrase for /home/niklas/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/niklas/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/niklas/.ssh/id_rsa)

niklas@llw ~ % killall ssh-agent

niklas@llw ~ % ssh-agent && ssh-add
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-TNMkMvgP8880/agent.8880; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=8881; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 8881;
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Why can I run `ssh-agent && ssh-add` only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I suggest you double check and make sure you didn't already have an agent running.  I suspect you had an agent already running.  Then you started a second, without properly updating the environment.  Your ssh-add communicated with the original agent.  Then you killed all the agents, and tried starting a new one without properly updating the environment, the following ssh-add couldn't contact the original agent, which you had killed.

Next you need to understand that when the SSH agent starts, it spits out a script that needs to be used to update your environment.  This is how client programs know how to contact the agent.  One way to do this is with a command like below.

```
. <(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. There was already an agent running, which is started *before* I log in, namely with the `use-ssh-agent` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.options` and its implementation in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent`. I now simply run `ssh-add`.